# Best way to replace repeated character in String

Tags: java, string, replace

I am given the String `"('allan', 'bob's', 'charles', 'dom')"`. Now I require this string but in the form `"('allan', 'bob''s', 'charles', 'dom')"`.

Notice I have replaced `bob's` with `bob''s` and that is all. My initial solution went along the lines of

```
String str = "('allan', 'bob's', 'charles', 'dom')";
String[] elements = str.substring(1, str.length()-1).split(", ");
String res = "(";
for (int j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
    res += "'"+ elements[j].substring(1, elements[j].length()-1).replace("'", "''") + "'" + ((j == elements.length - 1) ? ")" : ",' ");
}
```

Where res is the final solution. However I am wondering if there is a shorter, more elegant solution to this?

Comment: The requirements are unclear. Is bob the only name which can occur this way? You could try `str.replaceAll("'s'", "''s'");`

Comment: I think you will struggle to solve this in a way that handles all edge cases. You would be better doubling the quotes before creating the string. I also hope this is nothing to do with SQL, because you should use prepared statements.

Comment: By the way, your solution does not provide the required result. The comma's are missing.

Comment: Also note that `StringBuilder` is better suited when `String` concatenation occurs in loops

Comment: @Manu nope Bob is not the only one (any of which can). In regards to the comma, I have updated that - typo. Further information, the character after the quotation mark may not be 's'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replaceAll will work with `"'s"` as a regular expression.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
            String str = "('allan', 'bob's', 'charles', 'dom')";
            str = str.replaceAll("'s", "''s");
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

Output :

```
('allan', 'bob''s', 'charles', 'dom')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds like you just want to replace a single quote that is between two letters with two single quotes.  `String.replaceAll()` using the regex pattern `"(\\w)(['])(\\w)"` and replacement string `"$1''$3"` should get this done for you.

Pattern breakdown:

- `(\\w)` - Capture a letter or number into group 1
- `(['])` - Capture the single quote into group 2
- `(\\w)` - Capture a letter or number into group 3

Replacement string breakdown:

- `$1` - Capture group 1
- `''` - Two single quotes
- `$3` - Capture group 3

Code sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = "('allan', 'bob's', 'charles', 'dom')";
    str = str.replaceAll("(\\w)(['])(\\w)", "$1''$3");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Results:

```
('allan', 'bob''s', 'charles', 'dom')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.replace("'", "''").replaceAll("''(.*)?''(, *|\\)$)", "'$1'$2");
                                           (~~)   (~~~|~~~~)
```

Doubling the apostrophes cannot be done on a substring replace (without function-replace), hence must be done first.

Then one can pick out the quoted values, and correct them.

The trailer is either a comma+space or a final closing parenthesis.

`.*?` takes the shortest sequence.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend to fix the thing which outputted that string, and:

- use escape sequences
- use some library for reading/writing the data json or yaml might be good candidates